Generating function and currency
We assume that we have a country's currency that contains three coins worth 1, 3, and 4. How many ways can we get an amount of $n$ using these three pieces?
In others words what is the number of partitions of $n$ into $1, 3$, and $4$?
What is the answer if  $n=10$?
Is there a formula for the expression of $a_n$  in the general case of $n$?
This is equivalent to find the number  $a_n$ of positives integers $(a,b,c)$ solution of equation $a+3b+4c=n$, with $n$ positive integer.
It well known that the number is the coefficient $a_n$   of $x^n$   in the generating function
$\left(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots\right)\left(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\ldots\right)\left(1+x^4+x^8+x^{12}+\ldots\right)\dots$
What are the calculation methods?

What's your question?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have a look at https://oeis.org/A025767 and please report back on what you find there.

Thank you @GerryMyerson
I find the sequence $a_n$   for the G.f.: 1/((1-x)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)).
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 33, 35, 37, 40, 43, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 67, 70, 73, 77, 81, 84, 88, 92, 96, 100, 104, 108, 113, 117, 121, 126, 131, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 171, 176, 181, 187, 193, 198…
Then $a(10)=8$
And the formula
$a(n) = floor(n^2/24+n/3+1) $
I can verify in this formula
$a(n) = floor(100/24+10/3+1)=4+3+1=8 $

Good. You could post that as an answer to this question. Then you can accept your answer by clicking in the check mark next to it. This is an OK thing to do here, indeed, users are encouraged to post answers to their own questions, when they learn something that enables them to answer their questions.

Thank you Gerry Myerson
I find the sequence $a_n$ for the G.f.: $$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}$$
$1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 33, 35, 37, 40, 43, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 67, 70, 73, 77, 81, 84, 88, 92, 96, 100, 104, 108, 113, 117, 121, 126, 131, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 171, 176, 181, 187, 193, 198…$
Then $a_{10}=8$
And the formula $a_n=\lfloor(\frac{n^2}{24}+\frac{n}{3}+1)\rfloor$
We can verify in this formula $a_{10}=\lfloor(\frac{100}{24}+\frac{10}{3}+1)\rfloor=4+3+1=8$
That means, there are 8 ways to get an amount of 10 using coins worth 1, 3, and 4.
We can count the different ways: $(10,0,0);(7,1,0);(6,0,1);(4,2,0);(3,1,1);(2,0,2);(1,3,0); (0,2,1)$.
The set of all those triplets is the solution set of the equation $a+3b+4c=10$, $a,b$ and $c$ are positive integers.
Very nice application of generating functions, isn't it?
